# Xamarin OpenGL fragment shader weird behaviour when working with uniforms

Tags: ios, xamarin, opengl-es, fragment-shader

The fragment shader I'm currently working on has some quite weird behaviour which is driving me nuts. I have a frame buffer object which I'm rendering. In the fragment shader I also read from the same texture using my own written 'texelFetch' (which is not implemented by default as I'm using OpenGL ES):

```
vec4 texelFetch(sampler2D tex, ivec2 size, ivec2 coord)
{
    vec2 texCoord= vec2((2.0*float(coord.x) + 1.0)/(2.0*float(size.x)), (2.0*float(coord.y) + 1.0)/(2.0*float(size.y)));
    return texture2D(tex, texCoord);
}
```

This means I also need to know the size of the texture I am rendering when I called this function. The size of the texture is 1440x900 which is represented by an uniform in my shader:

```
uniform vec2 screenImageSize;
```

I set this value in my program as follows:

```
if (imageProgram != null)
            imageProgram.Use();

screenImageSizeUniform = imageProgram.GetUniformIndex("screenImageSize");
GL.Uniform2(screenImageSizeUniform, 1440.0f, 900.0f);


// Draw triangles that represents frame buffer rectangle
GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, 6);
```

The weird thing is that I don't receive the correct outputs  when I'm using this uniform.  I do receive the correct output when I hardcode the values however. In addition,  if I perform a check to see what the values are, I see that the uniform is set correctly:

```
//Following line does not give me the correct result as it seems to shift pixel values
//ivec2 test=ivec2(int(screenImageSize.x),int(screenImageSize.y));

//Following line does give me the correct result
ivec2 test=ivec2(1440,900);

if(test.x==1440 && test.y==900)
    gl_FragColor=texelFetch(previousFullImage,test,ivec2(gl_FragCoord.x,gl_FragCoord.y));
else
    gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated

[image: Different rendered images]

Note: the centre image is slightly rotated but that is due to me making the screenshot incorrectly.

Comment: What is "correct result" and what is "wrong result"? You are converting from float to int a lot, depending on the default precision this may "offset" things

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've included the images in the post and made the lower code block a little more explicit.
As far as I can see this is not due the conversions. I only do the conversion once and Ive tried playing with:

-Used highp for all values
-changed the attribute to `GL.Uniform2(screenImageSizeUniform, 1440.5f, 900.5f);`
Both did not seem to have an effect

Comment: Are you read and writing to the same texture?

Comment: ... and what hardware platform are you running on?

Comment: Yes I am reading and writing it from/to the same texture. I am running it on an iPhone 6+.

Comment: @AlexanderMaas: If you're doing that in the same rendering command, that's not allowed. Not unless you're using some extension that permits it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm using openTK  (ES 3.0). I am not aware that I'm using any special extension. I've changed the code such that the FBO contains a different texture than the input texture, but I still see the same result.

Comment: Given that the embedded constants of the same value as the uniforms work, I'd probably put this one down a bug in the GPU stack somewhere. Given what you are trying to do, it looks overly complicated though ... why not just use a varying value and a normal texure() call with single point sampling? This looks like a lot of effort per pixel, just to emulate textureFetch ...

Comment: @Isogen74 Hmm I hope you are not right, but I think you might be... The code is indeed overly complicated if I just want to copy a texture. Actually I'm combining data from several sources into one image. The location from which I need to take the data from these images is not always the same. I'll review my code and see whether I can simplify it to resemble what you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information that @Isogen74 provided, I concluded that it might indeed be a bug in the GPU stack somewhere. I therefore decided to look for a workaround and update to opengl es 3.0. `texelFetch` has been implemented there, without requiring the dimensions of the texture. Now it works like a charm! Thanks for all the help=)! Its really appreciated!